# Can't get onTouchListener to fire

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to get a touch listener to fire, but I can't make it work. Anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
public class FindEventsActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener, OnTouchListener {

    //lots of other code up here

    private void getFromCityState() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_state_entry, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(view);

        setContentView(R.layout.city_state_entry);
        city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
        state = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state_spinner);

        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        System.err.println("About to create onClickListener");
        submitButton.setOnTouchListener(this);


        return null;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        System.err.println("inside onTouch");
    }
```

}

My first println appears, but my second one does not. It must be the context where I am setting the onTouchListener, but I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnClickListener` instead of `setOnTouchListener` to handle click events on your button. It may be possible that `onTouch` isn't even triggered when a button is pressed.

Comment: It is triggered even when you move over button. But I agree for OnClickListener

Comment: I worked on OnClickListener prior to this method. Same results. I resolved it by declaring the listener in the XML file. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

You missed to override the onTouch method, and don't forget to return true. See the code below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("MY_LOG", "inside onTouch");
    return true;
}
```